# Adding similar elements basic misunderstanding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(10^n) + 9  (10^n)$

I don't understand the process behind converting this to

$10 *(10^n)$

how does one logically get from the first step to the second.

Comment: **Hint:** Factor $$10^n ( 1 + 9) = 10 * 10^n = 10^{n+1}$$

Comment: If you've got one of something, and you've also got nine more of that same thing, then all together you've got ten of that thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have like terms, you **add** their coefficients.

$$ac+bc = (a+b)c$$

Here, you have $10^n+9(10^n)$.

$$\implies \color{blue}{1}\color{purple}{(10^n)}+\color{blue}{9}\color{purple}{(10^n)} = \color{blue}{(1+9)}\color{purple}{10^n} = \color{blue}{10}(\color{purple}{10^n})$$

That’s how the expression is rewritten.

Answer (score 3):

Distribute:

$a + 9a = 1a + 9a = (1+9)a = 10a$.

So $10^n + 9*10^n = (1*10^n + 9*10^n) = 10^n(1 + 9) = 10^n*10 = 10^{n+1}$

Answer (score -1):

$$(10^n) + 9  (10^n)=(10^n) + (10-1) (10^n)=???$$